# R Requests Login to Login With Amazon to get Access Token for Amazon Advertising API

Tags: r, shiny, oauth-2.0, amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to build out a shiny web app on the localhost.  I am using R and trying to access the Amazon advertising API.  The documentation is on this site https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/setting-up/generate-api-tokens

I am not sure what type of set I am trying to build to get calls on my campaigns on the amazon seller account.  I set up the developer account and got the required sign Client ID and Secret Key.

It uses OAuth 2.0 and I thought I could get through the documentation and figure it out, but I am way in over my head.

Can anyone direct me on how to properly structure the OAuth code to access the API?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Amazon Advertising API Documentation is a tough one to crack in first attempt. I wonder why they have such obfuscated documentation. Ok, so here are the steps you need to follow

1) In the application that you registered, enter http://localhost as the redirect URI.

2) Visit this link in your browser, but replace CLIENT_ID and RETURN_URL with the values that you see in the web settings of your registered application.

https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=YOUR_LWA_CLIENT_ID &scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&response_type=code &redirect_uri=YOUR_RETURN_URL

Amazon has changed the links by Geography now. The default link above is for North America

For EU, use https://eu.account.amazon.com/ap/oa  as the URL

For Far East, use https://apac.account.amazon.com/ap/oa as URL

3)  Authenticate the account. Login using the Login with Amazon account you created before

4)  Copy the code that you will see in the localhost URL string. Please note that this code is valid for only 5 mins, so kindly have the next step ready before. In your R Notebook, run this code using your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET.  If your authorization code has lapsed, then repeat the step 1 of visiting the link.

Here also, Amazon has changed the URLs by Geography. The default URl given in code is now for North America.
For EU, use https://api.amazon.co.uk/auth/o2/token
For Far East, use https://api.amazon.co.jp/auth/o2/token

Use this R Code to get your Access and Refresh tokens. Save the refresh token immediately as that will be used in future to get access tokens.

#### Get the initial access and request tokens

library(httr)

headers = c(
    `Content-Type` = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
)

data = list(
  `grant_type`= 'authorization_code',
  `code`= 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE',
  `redirect_uri`= 'http://localhost',
  `client_id`= 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  `client_secret`= 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
)

response = POST(url = 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token', add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data , encode = "form")

## See the details of the access and refresh tokens using

content(response)$access_token

content(response)$refresh_token